How to add leading as options for throttle function?
I have an utility functions in TypeScript, named throttle, that I frequently use for controlling the execution rate of functions. However, I would like to extend these functions to support leading options.
Leading:

When leading is set to true, the function will be executed immediately on the first call. This means the function is triggered at the beginning of the wait period. For example, if you are throttling a function on a scroll event with a leading option, the function will be called as soon as the scroll starts.

These options allow developers to fine-tune control over function execution timing, accommodating specific use cases in their applications.
Here is the current implementation of the throttle function:
export function throttle(fn: (...args: any[]) => void, wait = 100) {
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | undefined;
    let lastTime = Date.now();

    const execute = (...args: any[]) => {
        lastTime = Date.now();
        fn(...args);
    };

    return (...args: any[]) => {
        const currentTime = Date.now();
        const elapsed = currentTime - lastTime;

        if (elapsed >= wait) {
            // If enough time has passed since the last call, execute the function immediately
            execute(...args);
        } else {
            // If not enough time has passed, schedule the function call after the remaining delay
            if (timeoutId !== undefined) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }

            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                execute(...args);
                timeoutId = undefined;
            }, wait - elapsed);
        }
    };
}


How can I modify the throttle function to include options for leading calls?
I would appreciate any example code or explanations on how to implement these options effectively. Thank you!
The following code is for test:
const sleep = (wait: number) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, wait));
(async () => {
    const wait = 100;
    const fn = ((...args: any[]) => console.log(args));
    const throttled = throttle(fn, wait);

    throttled('a', 'b', 'c'); // This should be called
    await sleep(wait - 5);
    throttled('b', 'a', 'c');
    await sleep(wait - 10);
    throttled('c', 'b', 'a'); // This should be called too

    await sleep(wait + 10); // Ensure we've waited long enough for it to be called twice
})


• It would help if you provided test cases showing what should happen with the desired implementation; they should be plain JS/TS tests without requiring a testing library. Indeed even how you want those options to be passed to the function isn't obvious; I'd imagine an options object (vs a bunch of parameters some of which you need to skip over)? • Does this approach meet your needs (assuming I've guessed correctly about the intended behavior and input format)? It's the minimum change afaik. If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Did you write the current function yourself? If not, where did you find it?

It seems your function already is set up to execute the callback on leading edges. The only problem with it is that let lastTime = Date.now(); is initialised incorrectly.

@Bergi I think the lastTime should be 0 at first? But if set lastTime to 0, then (elapsed >= wait) will always true

@DonHunt7382 It'll be true until the first call to execute() sets lastTime to a different value

@jcalz Sorry for the late response. Actually, the 'leading' parameter itself should be optional and default to true. The original function's 'fn' and 'wait' are required, with 'wait' defaulting to 100. So, in my understanding, the parameters should be like this: (fn, wait = 100, options = { leading: true }). As for the tests, I previously used Vitest just for convenience. If I am to provide basic test code, should I modify the post itself and add the test code?

@Bergi Got it. So maybe the default value of leading should be false

@jcalz Absolutely! Your modification is amazing, very clear and concise! I'll add the test code right away!

@jcalz Based on your modification, is the logic of this playground code correct if I want to add a trailing option?

• I'm confused about the purpose of your sleep()s, especially the final one, since those all get launched synchronously. Maybe you want to put stuff in an async function and then await each line so that you know things happen in a particular order? Not sure. • I suppose I'll write my answer, although I guess you do want that wait param separately. • That last comment looks like you're trying to ask a followup question here, where it doesn't belong. Not sure what to do with that.

@jcalz Just update the test script, I put sleep into async function

@jcalz Sorry, I forgot to add 0 at the end

... and that function doesn't do anything so it's hard to tell if it behaves as desired, right? No console.log() anymore? And you don't actually call your async function, and... well, I don't need a test suite, but you should have one, and presumably it should say what happens when you have leading on and off, and you want to do awaits everywhere, not just on sleep.  I'm going to stop worrying about the test code now because it seems like it's a digression and not actually helping anything.

@jcalz Because I'm using expect() from Vitest to count the number of calling test function, if for normal test, I can replace it with simple console.log. I updated it.

All you need to do to get leading to work is to initialise lastTime to -Infinity, so that the time elapsed on the first call of throttle from lastTime to currentTime will be Infinity and thus definitely greater than wait (assuming wait is some finite time):
function throttle(fn: (...args: any[]) => void, wait = 100, { leading = false } = {}) {
  // ⋯ 
  let lastTime = leading ? -Infinity : Date.now();
  // ⋯ same as existing version
}

I've added leading as a destructured function parameter which defaults to false and then set the entire options object to default to the empty object. So if you call throttle(fn, wait) it will behave like throttle(fn, wait, {}), which behaves like throttle(fn, wait, {leading: false}). If you want leading to be true then you should call throttle(fn, wait, {leading: true}).
Note also that since wait has a default argument, if you want to set options but not wait, you'll need to pass undefined in explicitly like throttle(fn, undefined, {leading: true}). Personally I'd say it's much cleaner to add wait to the options object like { wait = 100, leading = false } and then call thottle(fn, {wait: 1234}) or  throttle(fn, {leading: true}). But that's a digression from the question as asked.
Playground link to code

I sincerely apologize for any inconvenience caused during my questions, and thank you for your patience in assisting me to correct the issue and providing an accurate and perfect solution.
